# Problem with ZSH arrows' colors in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh, powerline

I've tried installing oh-my-zsh on my Windows 10 machine recently and everything is looking alright inside Windows Terminal,
ut when I try using it inside VSCode's integrated terminal, the colors are way off and the arrows' colors are different from the rest.

Imgur link to what my terminal looks like since Stack Overflow won't let me post any photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIppF.jpg

I've tried multiple Powerline fonts, modifying VSCode color theme and changing the terminal foreground color, but the result is always the same.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was perplexed by this as well, turns out it's something that recently broke in VS Code as a result of a [new accessibility feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_minimum-contrast-ratio-default-changed) introduced in version 1.66. The solution is to add the following to your VS Code settings.json file:

```
"terminal.integrated.minimumContrastRatio": 1,
```

Enforcing a minimum contrast ratio for terminal colors is a great idea that will help users with impaired vision, but an unintended consequence was that it would interfere with the way powerline-style tools render separator characters. Thankfully Microsoft offered us a way to disable it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I searched for two days and couldn't find any solution, I guess I should've taken a look at VSCode's changelogs then.

Comment: thank you, this has been bothering me!